# What are the caveats of namespace packages

Tags: python, packaging

Here in [Packaging namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/), it is mentioned that

> namespace packages can be useful for a large collection of
> loosely-related packages (such as a large corpus of client libraries
> for multiple products from a single company). **However, namespace
> packages come with several caveats and are not appropriate in all
> cases.** A simple alternative is to use a prefix on all of your
> distributions such as import `mynamespace_subpackage_a` (you could
> even use import `mynamespace_subpackage_a` as `subpackage_a` to keep
> the import object short).

But there are no examples. It is better to use the alternative?

Comment: Multiple different distributions with shared responsibility for managing a file tree greatly complicates the job of the installer/uninstaller (who owns the namespace itself? who should create/destroy the subdirectory in site-packages?). A bunch of existing tooling is flat out broken for namespace packages. It seems few people use them, or just forget about their existence, so bugs related to namespace packaging tend to hang around for ages. I avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are no examples.

The documentation refers to this example:

https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/tree/master/native

The documentation was written prior to the
[sunsetting](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2)
of python2.
Designing a solution that supports both {2,3}
would involve several caveats.

tl;dr: Given that you now should be targeting python3,
and 3.3+ at that,
then **using namespace packages** makes perfect sense.
(Current released interpreter is 3.11.)

Comment: This answer could be improved by quoting the relevant example, rather than just referring to an off-site resource.